# Travelling to the UK on an accompanied visa, unaccompanied

Tags: visas, uk

I am a Europen Union member and I applied for my brother to accompany me to the UK. He was granted an a visa to accompany to the UK and before the UK left the EU, I applied for settlement. I now live in the UK, can my brother come to the UK alone without me having to travelling from where he was to the UK? He is not a minor.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. What type of visa does your brother have? When was it issued and when does it expire? Does the visa name a specific person as a travel companion?

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think it's a duplicate. The to-be-accompanied person in that question was 17 and thus still a minor. Here, the OP's brother is "not a minor." The answer may well be different depending upon the to-be-accompanied person's age...that's the point of this question.

Comment: Without knowing the citizenship of the brother, no reliable answer can be given.